# Does Fluent Validation's SetInheritanceValidator method work for generics?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, fluentvalidation

Going off the documentation at https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/inheritance.html I'm using Fluent Validation AspNetCore 11.2, .NET Core 6. Seems to work fine with concrete examples but I'm not able to get it working with a generic class. Apologies if this has been answered but I'm not finding anything. The example is a message containing a payload object.

My class example:

```
public interface IMessage<T> where T : class, new() {
  T Payload { get; set; }
}

public class Message<T> : IMessage<T> where T : class, new() {
  T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Validator example:

```
public class MessageValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<Message<T>> where T : class, new() {
  public MessageValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Payload)
      .SetInheritanceValidator(val => {
        val.Add<Foo>(new FooValidator());
        val.Add<Bar>(new BarValidator());
      });
  }
}
```

Visual Studio complains about Foo and Bar with

```
CS0311 The type 'Foo' cannot be used as type parameter 'TDerived' in the generic type or method 'PolymorphicValidator<Message<T>, T>.Add<TDerived>(IValidator<TDerived>, params string[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Foo' to 'T'.
```

From what I've read I could probably achieve it with some of the deprecated MVC DI methods but would prefer to avoid that route. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.